# OrderBy clause not working on Microsoft SQL?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, laravel, eloquent

I was trying to recently changing my database from MariaDB to SQL server(Unfortunately not my call) on my Laravel web app. However, when I ran and opened one of my pages I got the error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

And this:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) AS aggregate
FROM [items]
     INNER JOIN (SELECT [model_name],
                        MAX(version) AS max_version
                 FROM [items]
                 WHERE [items].[deleted_at] IS NULL
                 GROUP BY [model_name]
                 ORDER by [created_at] ASC) [max_version_table] ON [items].[model_name] = [max_version_table].[model_name]
                                                              AND [items].[version] = [max_version_table].[max_version]
WHERE [items].[deleted_at] IS NULL;
```

I'm pretty new to SQL and here is my Eloquent ORM code:

```
public function AllModel(){
    $max_version_table = Item::select('model_name', DB::raw('MAX(version) as max_version'))->orderBy('created_at')->groupBy('model_name');

    $items = Item::select('*')->joinSub($max_version_table, 'max_version_table', function($join){
    $join->on('items.model_name','=','max_version_table.model_name');
    $join->on('items.version','=','max_version_table.max_version');
    })->paginate(5);    //Shows max version of each model name

    return view('admin.item.index',compact('items'));
}
```

My understanding is that MSSql doesn't support OrderBy since this works perfectly on MariaDB. If so may I ask what can I swap it for? Appreciate any help

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here; what about the error don't you understand? Also, *please* get into the habit of making good use of whitespace and linebreaks; single long lines of code are very difficult to read, and debug.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to sort in a subquery. The order is not guaranteed to be kept in the outer query.

Comment: I, personally, don't see why you are using a subquery at all. Looking at your query, the same result could be given by the query `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT model_name) AS aggregate FROM dbo.Items WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND version IS NOT NULL;` (If `Version` isn't `NULL`able, then the clause `version IS NOT NULL` can be omitted.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSSQL definitely supports `order by` but in your case as the error already suggested

> The `ORDER BY` clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions

You cannot use `order by` in `subqueries` like you have done.
Go through the [mssql order by documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)  for more understanding

And by looking at your query I think its unnecessary to add any `order by` as it is doing nothing. You can remove the clause.

```
SELECT count(*) AS AGGREGATE
FROM [items]
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT [model_name],
          MAX(VERSION) AS max_version
   FROM [items]
   WHERE [items].[deleted_at] IS NULL
   GROUP BY [model_name]
) AS [max_version_table] ON [items].[model_name] = [max_version_table].[model_name]
AND [items].[version] = [max_version_table].[max_version]
WHERE [items].[deleted_at] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server definitely supports ORDER BY, but your query should look like

```
select count(*) as aggregate 
from [items] 
inner join 
(
  select [model_name], MAX(version) as max_version from [items] where [items].      [deleted_at] is null group by [model_name] 
) as [max_version_table] 
on 
 [items].[model_name] = [max_version_table].[model_name] 
    and [items].[version] = [max_version_table].[max_version] 
where [items].[deleted_at] is null
```